# Android Studio Project Can't Use AVD

Tags: android-studio

I'm starting to use Android Studio for the first time, and I've run into a snag. When I followed an example and made a helloworld app, no problem. However, I tried to make my own app, which was literally just a Blank Activity, and it can't use Android Tools, or the AVD. I then deleted this project from both AS and in Windows Explorer, and remade it, multiple times. It never fixed the problem. This app was called D&D 5e Character Roller.

I then made another app called DnD 5e Character Roller, which did not have the same problem - it can use AVD and Android Tools.

At this point, I believe that it may simply be due to the ampersand in the name of the first app, but this seems like a weird reason for it to fail - it at least should have told me that would be a problem when I was trying to make the app. Is this a known problem with AS? My searching turned up nothing related to it. If not, what is the problem? If you are at home, can you try to make a similarly named project(with an ampersand) and see if you can use AVD/Android Tools, which would make it a problem with my install of AS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should have opened the module setting of your project, there sdk path or gradle version should be missing.

Comment: The weird thing is that it's off of a new project. At the same time I was having this problem, I was also able to make new projects that didn't have the problem.